# NSInvalidArgumentException getting value of property after generating a grid of buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I hope this isn't a duplicate question. I looked for something similar but I couldn't find anything, and the error message is very vague so that could lead to a duplicate question.

I have a view controller that receives a custom object. The .h file is like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Tile.h"

@interface TilesVC : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Tile *tileToFind;

@end
```

Then the implementation file starts like this:

```
#import "TilesVC.h"

#define kButtonColumns 26
#define kButtonRows 36

@interface TilesVC ()
{
    UIButton *buttons[kButtonColumns][kButtonRows];
}
@end

@implementation TilesVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"tile = %@", self.tileToFind.tile_personName);
    [self generateTiles];
    NSLog(@"tile = %@", self.tileToFind.tile_personName);
}

- (void)generateTiles
{
    NSInteger intTagNumber  = 0;
    NSInteger intXTile;
    NSInteger intYTile;

    float tileWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width / kButtonColumns;
    float tileHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height / (kButtonRows + 1);

    char char_x = 'A';

    for (int x = 0; x < kButtonColumns; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= (kButtonRows + 1); y++)
        {
            intXTile  = x * tileWidth;
            intYTile = y * tileHeight;

            // create a value button, text, or image
            buttons[x][y] = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(intXTile, intYTile, tileWidth, tileHeight)];
            [buttons[x][y] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"square_black"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [buttons[x][y] setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            buttons[x][y].adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
            buttons[x][y].adjustsImageWhenDisabled = NO;
            buttons[x][y].tag = intTagNumber;
            buttons[x][y].enabled = NO;
            [self.view addSubview:buttons[x][y]];

            intTagNumber++;
        }
        char_x ++;
    }
}
```

As you can see there are 2 identical NSLog calls. The first one executes properly (output's the person's name as expected) while the second one crashes with an exception being thrown. Here's the first part of the log output of the crash:

```
2015-04-09 10:12:38.670 Test_ParseCSVtoTile[1122:31926] -[UIButton tile_personName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78933e90
2015-04-09 10:12:38.673 Test_ParseCSVtoTile[1122:31926] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton tile_personName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78933e90'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x008e2466 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0056ba97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x008ea2c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00832bc7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0083278e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Test_ParseCSVtoTile                 0x000843f2 -[TilesVC viewDidLoad] + 258
    6   UIKit                               0x00deff24 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 771
    7   UIKit                               0x00df0215 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x00e197bd -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 773
    9   UIKit                               0x00e27466 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
    10  UIKit                               0x00e280b2 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
```

When the second log executes the `tileToFind` is nil.

Any idea why the property becomes nil after calling the `generateTiles` method?

**EDIT**
The tileToFind variable gets assigned on a previous/different view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"segueSearchToTile"])
    {
        Tile *tileFound = (Tile *)sender;
        TilesVC *tvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        tvc.tileToFind = tileFound;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The error indicates that your `titleToFind` property has been assign a `UIButton` instance instead of a `Title` instance. Where do you assign `self.titleToFind`?

Comment: I modified the question to include the assignment. Thanks

Comment: There's your problem. `sender` is a `UIButton`, not a `Title`. Using the cast doesn't change that fact.

Comment: But im calling it like this:     Tile *tileFound = [self findTileByPersonID:self.textField_id.text];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueSearchToTile" sender:tileFound];

Comment: Even if that's the case, why does it work because generating a ton of buttons?

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code. See what `sender` really is.

Comment: sender = (Tile *) 0x79f65e40

Comment: OK, then `titleToFind` is being set to a `UIButton` somewhere else. Again, use the debugger and figure out where.

Comment: Yeah that's what I have no idea why. You've seen all the code involved here. In fact, the if I make the same log call in the loop to make the buttons, it outputs on all except the very last button